# How to get table data based by version

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have student table like this:

[image]

Initially there was 2 records in version 0. Whenever I made any change in record it always create new entry in table with new record id but same student_id and new version. This is to be done for version management and backtracking of data.

Now I run below query for get data for version 0:

```
SELECT * FROM tblStudent as a
inner join (
select student_id, max(record_id) as MaxRecordID from tblStudent group by student_id
) b on a.student_id=b.student_id and a.record_id = MaxRecordID
where a.version=0
```

As latest reocord will have maximum `record_id` so i did group by `student_id` and get only that record which is having maximum record_id.

But its give me wrong ouput. Problem is I can't write having `version=0` condition in inner join query while group by student_id.

Comment: why do you group data instead of just using where clause

Comment: please understand problem first.

Comment: show what your expected outcome is

Comment: first 3 rows should be come in result when i want version 0 data.

Comment: and 2nd, 3rd and 5th record should be come when i want data of version 1

Comment: Hmm, would this be more straightforward: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tblStudent where version=0) as a inner join ...`? Basically if you just want info of version 0 why not filter those first.

Comment: i want a common query which give me data of any version which i ask.

Comment: Why are there two changes to 'student_id' 1 but the second change doesn't change the `version`

Comment: basicallly there is version release funtionality in my tool so unless and until you release version all changes will be saved in same version . so there may be multiple record in same version. we just need to fetch max record id data because that contains latest change.

Comment: Also why do you want the 2nd and 3rd records when you ask for version 1, when they are version 0?

Comment: 0 is base version. So version 1 should contains unchahged record of version 0 plus version 1's latest updated records.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. I am presuming you are passing the version as a parameter to the query.

```
create table #temp1(
recordid int, 
student_id int,
student_name varchar(5),
version int
)

insert into #temp1
values(1,1,'aaa',0)

insert into #temp1
values(2,2,'bbb',0)

insert into #temp1
values(3,3,'ccc',0)

insert into #temp1
values(4,1,'aa1',1)

insert into #temp1
values(5,1,'aa2',1)


declare @version int = 0;

with cte (recordid, student_id) 
as (select max(recordid) , student_id 
      from #temp1 
      where version <= @version group by student_id
   ) 
select cte.recordId, t.student_id, t.version, t.student_name 
from cte 
inner join #temp1 t on t.recordid = cte.recordid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number() over ( partion by Student_Id order by version)`.
See this [example](http://rextester.com/VQNXL70494)

```
CREATE TABLE tblStudent(Record_Id INT, Student_Id INT, Student_Name nvarchar(50) , Version INT)

INSERT INTO tblStudent(Record_Id, Student_Id, Student_Name, Version)
VALUES 
(1,1,'aaa',0),
(2, 2, 'bbb', 0),
(3,3,'aaa',0),
(4,1,'aa1',1),
(5,1,'aa2',2)

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Student_Id ORDER BY Version ASC) Ranking
    FROM tblStudent
) sub
WHERE sub.Ranking = 1
```

The select * should be changed

If you want the latest version, you can use `DESC` instead of `ASC`. Check the execution plan to add the correct index based on the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach :

```
create table #t (record_id int, student_id int, student_name varchar(50), version int)
insert into #t values
(1,1,'aaa',0),
(2,2,'bbb',0),
(3,3,'ccc',0),
(4,1,'aa1',1),
(5,1,'aa2',1)

select * from #t

declare @ver int;
set @ver = 1;  --configurable as 0 or 1

SELECT a.* FROM #t as a
inner join (
select student_id, max(record_id) as MaxRecordID from #t group by student_id
) b on a.student_id=b.student_id 
where (
        (@ver = 1 and  (a.record_id = b.MaxRecordID))
        or
        (@ver = 0) and  (a.version = 0)
    )
order by a.student_id
```

**replace #t with tblStudent**